# getCurrentTextColor from a TextView returns a weird color

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the text color from a textView and compare it, to do some action or any other.

```
if (tvTitle.getCurrentTextColor() == -48060){
    isAccepted = 1;
}
```

As you can see, at the moment I've to compare it as "-48060" because this is what `getCurrentTextColor()` is returning.

The original color is #ff4444

Do I've to parse this -48060 in any way to get ff4444?

Thanks.

Comment: Color class has a static method to parse strings.

Comment: Note that the leading "F" in the hex value (or more specifically a leading "1" in the binary value) indicates a negative `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just treat it as unsigned int.

I'm 99% positive that the actual color is `0xffff4444` - the two extra "f's" are for alpha. The most significant bit is set, which means, that if the value is interpreted as an int, it will be a negative value. If you cast it to an unsigned int, you will get a rather large positive number.

If all you want to do is compare the value like you do in your code, you can also put a hex value there, for example :

```
if (tvTitle.getCurrentTextColor() == 0xff4444){
    isAccepted = 1;
}
```

Comment: You might want to define this color value in `colors.xml`, instead of having a "magic" value in your Java code.

Comment: well actually this is the light red holo color, programmers can find it familiar. Anyways totally right, a value in colors would be great, but even greater if this color is taken directly from Android and not defined by myself.