# How to change the text color on a TextView by clicking it?

Tags: android, textview

First of all, I declared my values j, u as integers because text.getCurrentTextColor() and text.setTextColor() take only integers.
Then I created an `OnClickListener()` method, so that when I click it, it runs the code inside the method.
After that I created two `if` conditions that will continuously switch the text color either to color id "j" or color id "u".

I ran the program on my device and when I clicked it, the text just disappeared and never came back again.

Im new to programming, and I can't find the answer to my problem in any posts.

Did I understand the `OnClickListener()` event correctly?
And is `android:clickable="true"` necessary?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourlabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LabelText"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Java

```
        final int j=100000; //Color id number
        final int u=690856; //Color id number
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourlabel);
        text.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                       if(j==text.getCurrentTextColor())
                       {
                           text.setTextColor(u);
                       }
                        else
                       {
                           text.setTextColor(j);
                       }

                    }

                }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood the onClickListener correctly and no, you do not have to use `android:clickable="true"` in this case.
The problem you are facing is that `getCurrentTextColor()` returns other values than you are expecting. A detailed answer can be found here: 
[getCurrentTextColor from a TextView returns a weird color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137489/getcurrenttextcolor-from-a-textview-returns-a-weird-color)

To fix your code you should declare your colors in colors.xml like this:

```
<color name="yourFirstColor">#0097A7</color>
<color name="yourSecondColor">#536DFE</color>
```

In your Activity you can get the colors via:

```
final int j = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yourFirstColor);
final int u = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yourSecondColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to change.
Try something like this...

```
Handle handler;
```

Then on your onCreate initialize it

```
handler = new Handler();
```

And for a flexible solution I am creating a method

```
private void changeTextColor(TextView tv, int color){
handler.post(new Runnable(){
@Override
private void run(){
text.setTextColor(color);
}
});
}
```

This should work...