# How Get textcolor as argb from textview android?

Tags: java, android

`textOut.CurrentTextColor;`
How to get Argb from it.
I have been tried many time with different function with no avail.
May anyone Help me ?

Comment: textView.getCurrentTextColor() return you the integer value, which is the same as the ARGB version of the color if compared correctly, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137489/getcurrenttextcolor-from-a-textview-returns-a-weird-color)

Comment: I know but How to convert it to hex Have you got any function as example ?! I mean for example ```-1``` to ``#FFFFFFFF`` or To ```Argb``` byte ?

Comment: Have you tried with this solution? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540378/2910520)